# Photos taking too much space on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, photos, storage

I was clearing up my Mac to download the latest Os X, but when I saw the "Photos" in "About this Mac" are taking 9 GB space! Any idea where I can find all these photos?

Comment: Try opening the Photos app.

Comment: You’re probably looking for the “optimize Mac storage” option in Photos.app’s iCloud preferences. Maybe you even want to deactivate the iCloud photo library (or stream or both) on your MBA altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The **Photos.app** imported images/movies are stored in the **Photos Library** in the **Pictures** folder, along with other individual pictures, within your **Home** folder.  You can access the **Pictures** folder in **Finder**.

Answer (score 1):

Photo application keeps all the pictures inside is library: **Photos Library**.

The location of the library is the following: `~/Users/<user_name_here>/Pictures`.

Anyway, you can open the application Photos and choose one by one if keep or not any photo.

[image]